# Generating response data type of rest api call when using Octokit with typescript classes

Tags: typescript, github-actions, octokit-js

I am having difficulty in finding a good way to generate types for Octokit rest API calls. It seems like my requirements might be a bit out of the norm.

Here's what I am trying to do. I am creating a custom action in typescript and I have a class as follows.

```js
import {debug} from '@actions/core'
import {getOctokit} from '@actions/github'
import type {GetResponseDataTypeFromEndpointMethod} from '@octokit/types'

const octokit = getOctokit('')
type Pull = GetResponseDataTypeFromEndpointMethod<typeof octokit.rest.pulls.get>

export class GitHubService {
  private readonly octokit

  constructor(gitHubToken: string) {
    this.octokit = getOctokit(gitHubToken)
  }

  async handlePullRequestChange(
    repositoryOwner: string,
    repositoryName: string,
    pullRequestNumber: number
  ): Promise<Pull> {
    const pull = await this.octokit.paginate(this.octokit.rest.pulls.get, {
      owner: repositoryOwner,
      repo: repositoryName,
      pull_number: pullRequestNumber
    })

    debug(`Pull request ${pullRequestNumber} includes the following body: ${JSON.stringify(pull)}`)

    return pull
  }
}
```

I am creating the `GitHubService` class from a `main.ts` and as you can see, I am passing the token in the constructor and which is creating the `octokit` object required for calling the APIs. Then I want to call `handlePullRequestChange` and I want this function to return the response from the octokit api call with proper typing.

I am having trouble generating the types properly. The above codebase is something that works statically but will probably break as `getOctokit('')` will fail since I am passing an empty token.

The other way could be to create the `type` inside the function like

```js
  async handlePullRequestChange(
    repositoryOwner: string,
    repositoryName: string,
    pullRequestNumber: number
  ): Promise<Pull> {
    type Pull = GetResponseDataTypeFromEndpointMethod<typeof this.octokit.rest.pulls.get>
    const pull: Pull = await this.octokit.paginate(this.octokit.rest.pulls.get, {
      owner: repositoryOwner,
      repo: repositoryName,
      pull_number: pullRequestNumber
    })

    debug(`Pull request ${pullRequestNumber} includes the following body: ${JSON.stringify(pull)}`)

    return pull
  }
```

But this won't compile as the the function's return type of `Promise<Pull>` doesn't have access to `Pull` yet. I know I can just not give the return type explicitly but I want to maintain my linting setup and I am maintaining explicit return types on functions.

What can I do in here?